# Ant replace task doesn't work

Tags: powershell, ant

I have Powershell script. It has a first line:

```
$installation_folder = @aaa@
```

And have an Ant buildfile with this task:

```xml
<target name="prepare-install-script" description="Preparation of installation script">
    <replace file="install.ps1" propertyfile="${template-properties}">
        <replacefilter token="@aaa@" value="installation.dir"/>
    </replace>
</target>
```

All files are initialized. Logs said:

```
[replace] Replacing in c:\Users\install.ps1: @aaa@ --> sdfsdf
```

But in the file nothing changed.

What can it be?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Are you certain that all variables/properties are initialized correctly and all files are where Ant thinks they are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that when you write script in PowerShell default Windows IDE it became somethings like "binary" file with some system information. That's why Ant can't do replacing.
Fixing by copy script to simply text editor and save as ps1.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the encoding. This will work:

```
<target name="prepare-install-script" description="Preparation of installation script">
<replace file="install.ps1" token="@aaa@" value="installation.dir" encoding="UTF-16"/>
```